# Google maps : limits on number of points, vertices and polygons

Tags: google-maps, limit

I simply cannot find a usage limit for this particular feature on google maps. I know for sure they have a complete documentation on usage limits like number of requests/map loads per day. But regarding drawing tools, I especially like polygons. How many points can you plot, how polygons can you draw?

Or at least in your common experiences, how many polygons drawn on a single map instance does it take till the application crashes or the map fails to load?

Comment: There are no limits on objects on the map other than _your_ computer's memory and processing power and the particular browser you are using.  So this is not something Google would need to document.

Comment: When I was using polygons to outline boundaries of cities, it seems google maps has restricted the number of points to something like 256 points for a single polygon. That's because when it reaches it's limit, it will no longer allow me to grab another soft point of the polygon, which then would turn into a hard point of the polygon (another set of coordinates recorded within the polygon tag in XML programming language).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google does not impose any usage restrictions on any of the overlays including polygons, markers, etc. I have used over hundred polygons on my map without any issue from Google. However depending on how many points are present in the polygon the application may crash. I had that issue when I was plotting a polygon with over 4000 points. A workaround is plotting the polygons when they are required.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer?csw=1

Answer (score 0):

I am writing an app that displays plots of land as separate polygons on a map. Most polygons have 4 vertices, but some are much more complex.
The app displays the html through a webbrowser component.
I've found the limit to be about 3500 polygons.