# Getting Polyline from Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, google-polyline

Can I retrieve all the coordinates as `LatLng` that is stored in Firestore from different documents and use the coordinates to build a route using the Polyline in GoogleMap API. Or do I need to save it in Array in Firestore to be able to do so? I am making a route from 3 to 4 coordinates in the Firestore is it possible or is it just 2 coordinates is the max in making the Polyline as the destination and starting point. Thank you in advance. Any documentation is appreciated as well.

Image of my Firestore:
[image: Firestore Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I retrieve all the coordinates as LatLng that is stored in Firestore from different documents and use the coordinates to build a route using the Polyline in GoogleMap API.

As I see in your screenshot, the location field in your database is of type GeoPoint. So you need to create a query, loop through the results, create a new LatLng object of each location, and add all of them to the polyline.

> Or do I need to save it in Array in Firestore to be able to do so.

That's nothing mandatory. Save them to an array only if those are your requirements.

> I am making a route from 3 to 4 coordinates in the Firestore is it possible or is it just 2 coordinates is the max in making the Polyline as the destination and starting point.

You can add as many coordinates as you want into a Polyline.

- [Google maps : limits on number of points, vertices and polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501782/google-maps-limits-on-number-of-points-vertices-and-polygons/26314254#26314254)

**Edit:**

If you are using only the origin and the destination, the following code will work fine:

```
PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(googleAPiKey,
        _originLatitude, _originLongitude, _destLatitude, _destLongitude);
print(result.points);
```

However, if you need more than that, you indeed need a List of points:

```
List<PointLatLng> result = polylinePoints.decodePolyline("_p~iF~ps|U_ulLnnqC_mqNvxq`@");
print(result);
```

More info is below:

- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_polyline_points

Comment: Thank you so so much i think i know how should i approach it, just that the part where i put in multiple coordinates into the Polyline is the problem. Do you perhaps as any basic code or example of how to set all the coordinates into the Polyline? Is it done in a `List`? Cause i found an example that are using `List` to save multiple coordinates into the Polyline. Thank you so much once again.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will definitely make it work with your help. Thanks mate.

Comment: If i have further inquiries in the future regarding this, can i comment here good sir?

Comment: No, you should post new questions, here on Stackoverflow. Don't add them as comments.